# How can I XCopy on http?

Tags: windows, command-line, sharepoint

So SharePoint is painful, and I need to get all the documents out of a SharePoint site. I have discovered that I can simply paste the URL into a Windows Explorer address bar, and navigate the file structure.

But I cannot do that from a cmd prompt.

I was hoping to start by getting something ike this to work:

```
C:\>dir "https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/DocumentManagementSystem/Folder1"
```

and then I would be able to

```
C:\>xcopy "https://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/DocumentManagementSystem/Folder1" etc.
```

Is there a way to get this working on a command prompt, rather than than using the drag and drop with file explorer windows?

Comment: Are you sure it works? Xcopy works on files, as far as I know. There are many tools to download a website's content recursively (wget for example), but I doubt these will work on a SharePoint server's web interface. Altough... I just found this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41346/how-to-download-a-sharepoint-directory-with-wget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map a network drive to a SharePoint Online site, follow these steps:

1. Sign in to the SharePoint Online site by using your Office 365 work or school account credentials. Make sure that you select the Stay signed in option.
2. Right-click Computer or This PC from the Desktop or within Windows Explorer, and then click Map Network Drive.
3. Click the Connect to a Web site that you can store your documents and pictures link, and then click Next two times.
4. Type the site URL, click Next, and then follow the instructions in the wizard. For example, type https://contoso.sharepoint.com.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2616712/how-to-configure-and-to-troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives-that-connec

Comment: Unbelievable. And to think how I've been struggling to work with the crappy SharePoint web Interface all this time, trying to use the folder system. Thank you.